# JavaFX plot a chart: how to assign values in a class

Tags: java, javafx

I was trying to create a class which can plot xy charts by modifying the example in http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm. The codes are provided below. How can I change the data and title? If I set lineChart.setTitle(title); as lineChart.setTitle("abc"); it will work, but when I use a variable name. It doesn't.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PlotLines extends Application {
private String title;
private String xLab;
private String yLab;
double [][] xy;

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setxLab(String xLab) {
    this.xLab = xLab;
}

public void setyLab(String yLab) {
    this.yLab = yLab;
}

public void setxy(double[][] xy) {
    this.xy = xy;
}

public void plot(){
    launch();
}


@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    //stage.setTitle(title);
    //defining the axes
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel(xLab);
    yAxis.setLabel(yLab);

    //creating the chart
    final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart =
            new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

    lineChart.setTitle(title);
    //defining a series
    XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
    series.setName("Data Points");
    //populating the series with data

    //System.out.println(xy.length);

    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 23));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 14));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 24));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 34));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 36));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7.5, 22));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 45));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 43));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 17));

    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 29));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 25));

    Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);
    lineChart.getData().add(series);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
}
```

The following codes are to call this this class

```
public class PlotExample  {



public static void main(String[] args) {

    double [][] xy = {{1.,2.},{3.,5.},{6.,7.}};

    PlotLines aa = new PlotLines();
    aa.setTitle("CGM");
    aa.setxLab("Time");
    aa.setyLab("Glucose");
    aa.setxy(xy);

    aa.plot();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application doesn't get started correctly.

You have a class `PlotExample` with a `main` method. In that class you create an instance of `PlotLines`, set the values and call the `plot` method which launches the application.

In your case, the application is an instance of `PlotLines`. What happens when an application is launched is documented in in the [JavaFX API:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html)

> The entry point for JavaFX applications is the Application class. The JavaFX runtime does the following, in order, whenever an application is launched:
>
> 1. Constructs an instance of the specified Application class
> 2. Calls the init() method
> 3. Calls the start(javafx.stage.Stage) method
> 4. Waits for the application to finish, which happens when either of the following occur:
>
>    - the application calls Platform.exit()
>    - the last window has been closed and the implicitExit attribute on Platform is true
> 5. Calls the stop() method

As documented, in the first step an instance of the application is constructed (here: an instance of `PlotLines`). This instance has `null` values for title and axis labels. **The original instance of `PlotLines` is ignored.**

To fix this, you should call `launch` before anything else and build your model in the `start` method of your application like it is done in the example.

For your code, you could do something like this:

```
public class PlotExample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // stage.setTitle(title);
        // defining the axes

        double[][] xy = { { 1., 2. }, { 3., 5. }, { 6., 7. } };

        PlotLines aa = new PlotLines();
        aa.setTitle("CGM");
        aa.setxLab("Time");
        aa.setyLab("Glucose");
        aa.setxy(xy);


        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel(aa.getxLab());
        yAxis.setLabel(aa.getyLab());

        // creating the chart
        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle(aa.getTitle());
        // defining a series
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("Data Points");
        // populating the series with data

        // System.out.println(xy.length);

        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 23));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 14));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 24));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 34));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 36));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7.5, 22));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 45));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 43));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 17));

        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 29));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 25));

        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class PlotLines {
    private String title;
    private String xLab;
    private String yLab;
    double[][] xy;

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setxLab(String xLab) {
        this.xLab = xLab;
    }

    public void setyLab(String yLab) {
        this.yLab = yLab;
    }

    public void setxy(double[][] xy) {
        this.xy = xy;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getxLab() {
        return xLab;
    }

    public String getyLab() {
        return yLab;
    }

    public double[][] getXy() {
        return xy;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! kind of solve it under your direction. Now a new problem came out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427725/javafx-reusable-line-chart-for-xyplot